# nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "nlb-url>on one env

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx installed on an AWS instance but from 2 days it is down more than one time at a day and gives 503 error with nginx: `[emerg] host not found in upstream "nlb-url>`
every time I have this issue I need to restart the nginx and apache and this make them works correctly and I don't know what is the exact issue that
this screenshot when I check the status of nginx
[image]

Comment: please use nginx -t  and share the output here.
also have you define and upstream(nlb) in conf

Comment: hi rakesh, this is the output for nginx -t ```nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2021/10/15 12:09:31 [warn] 2520#2520: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:1
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
2021/10/15 12:09:31 [emerg] 2520#2520: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (13: Permission denied)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed``` and I didn't  define any upstream in conf

Comment: please run  nginx -t using sudo user .

Comment: this is the output: ```nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful```

Comment: have you using any proxy for the vhost . its may be issue with proxy host.

Comment: no I don't use it only nginx as reverse proxy and it send the request to NLB then to a machine with apache running in it

Comment: may be issue with nlb/apache host.

Comment: when I restart nginx , everything is going to be ok and I don't know the reason

Answer (score 0):

after I do a lot of searches, I found the solution which is to add in the configuration file a resolver to resolve the DNS name and make the host which was not found as a variable :

```
    resolver       8.8.8.8;
    set $host_dns  blabla.amazon.com;
    proxy_pass     $host_dns;
```